# What's the tensor network representation for local ground state?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, topological-order, lattice-model, tensor-network

It's well known that many topological phases can be represented using matrix product state and PEPS. Example, toric code, $H=-\sum_{v}A_v-\sum_p B_p $. My question is:

What's the tensor network representation for local ground state?

Here Local ground state means the ground state $H'$ on whole lattice which only contains some terms of $H$ that has nonzero support contained in a sub-region $B$.

The following is a concrete example.

[image: toric code]

Only the terms in the green boxed are not omitted. My main concern is how to deal with the bond indexes on the boundary.

Comment: Can you be more precise what you mean with "local ground state"?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch The ground state of a new Hamiltonian that only contain some terms of original Hamiltonian (on a local patch)

Comment: Sure, but which terms exactly?  Which are omitted? Could you *please* be more precise?  I'm pretty sure there is a succint answer to your question if you ask it in a succinct way, but otherwise, it's just too much work to write it in the utmost generality.

Comment: Thanks for your patience! I have did some updates. My main concern is how to deal with the bond indexes on the boundary.

Comment: Well, the local ground state is not unique.  Thus, *any* choice of boundary conditions (i.e,. of the bond indices at the boundary) gives a valid ground state.  See e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.4596.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch  So, different anyonic excitations out of the region correspond to different bond indices at the boundary? How to determine those $\alpha$ from the anyonic excitation outside the region?